# On sentences true in all finite groups (revisited)

Tags: gr.group-theory, lo.logic

Let $w$ be a group word with variables $\bar x, \bar y$, where
$\bar x=(x_1,\dots ,x_m)$ and
$\bar y=(y_1,\dots ,y_n).$ 
I am interested in the following questions.

(1) Is the sentence $(\forall\bar x)(\exists\bar y)w=1$
true in every group if it is true in every finite group?

(2) Is the sentence $(\exists\bar x)(\forall\bar y)w=1$  true in every group if it is true in every finite group?

For $m=2$ and $n=4$ the answer to (1)
is negative, in general, as shown in [T. Coulbois, A. Khelif,
Proc. AMS 127 (1999), No. 4, 963--965](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1999-127-04/S0002-9939-99-04747-4/S0002-9939-99-04747-4.pdf).

In  [On sentences true in all finite groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207438/on-sentences-true-in-all-finite-groups)
I asked the questions (1) and (2) for $m=n=1$.

Bjørn Kjos-Hanssen gave positive answers to these questions.
In fact, his answers can be generalized: 
an answer is positive for (1) if $m=1$, and for (2) if $n=1$.
The open questions I want to ask:

> (a) Is  $(\forall xy)(\exists z)w(x,y,z)=1$
>   true in every group if it is true in every finite group?
>
> (b) Is  $(\exists x)(\forall yz)w(x,y,z)=1$  true in every group if it is true in every finite group?

Comment: This time it will have to involve non-abelian groups it seems.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Also, I guess that, probably, answers to these questions are negative.

Comment: About (2): The sentence $\exists x\forall y_1,\dots,y_k:w(x,y_1,\dots,y_k)=1$ holds in every group iff it holds in a free group of countable rank, iff $w(1,y_1,\dots,y_k)=1$ as abstract word. I'm not sure if the same conclusion if the above sentence is only supposed to hold in every finite group.